# Filter Data in Serialization Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have serialization class like this

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = Menu.objects.raw('''SELECT menu_menu.*, menu_permission.role_id FROM menu_menu
                               JOIN menu_permission ON menu_menu.id = menu_permission.menu_id 
                               WHERE sub_menu_id IS NULL  
                               ORDER BY menu_menu.id ASC''')
    subItems = SubMenuSerializer(data=data,many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('id',
                 'label',
                 'icon',
                 'link',
                 'isTitle',
                 'isMenuCollapse',
                 'subItems')
```

how to filter `subItems` based request header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to go.

Serializers serialize data but don't extract it, you "choose" the data to be shown in the controller ( viewset, in DRF lang ).

Check this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Anyway, you can access the request information using the method "save" in the serializer, it is in the var named "context". You can find it in the documentation too.